# Hot Deploy with Eclipse & Tomcat throwing ServletException

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I've had it working and then made some style changes and it seemed to stop (<- might be a red herring). The file /hv/header.jsp hasn't moved and eclipse can still find it.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: File &quot;/hv/header.jsp&quot; not found
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.handleMissingResource(JspServlet.java:335)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:301)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.jsp.layout_002d4area_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fimport_005f0(layout_002d4area_jsp.java:1332)
    at org.apache.jsp.layout_002d4area_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f1(layout_002d4area_jsp.java:605)
    ...
```

I shortened the stack track but can paste the entire one.

Comment: can you please check your jsp that is there any error in it, b/c it seems to me that your jsp didn't compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by making a new workspace.

Comment: So, we can expect you to come back after some days/weeks when you get tired of recreating workspace everytime? :)

Comment: Probably. It happens sporadically and the answer above doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have a tag like  note the ' char in the file name... this is probably the cause.